# Is there a way to specify the name of the autoincrement id in Django?

Tags: django-models, auto-increment, field-names

How can I change the field name of Django's  autoincrement from `id` to something like `tablename_id`?

I want to do it in the model definition itself.

The autoincrement key is created automatically do there doesn't seem a way to set it via the `db_column` attribute.

Comment: I solved it by usingAutoField and set the primary key.`tablename_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ModelTest(models.Model):
    tablename_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

I hope I've helped.